# trouble creating jsp file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

When I right click on a folder and choose New...JSP file in eclipse project view, nothing happens.  How can I fix this so that a new JSP is created in the designated folder when I right click on the folder?

I should note that I am using the same structure from [this tutorial.](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-hibernate-maven-crud/)

Should I also move the application.properties file to be outside the Java Resources folder?

Comment: This sounds like an Eclipse problem. Check the log file.

Comment: Note that `src/main/webapp` should not be a source folder. It should not be on the classpath.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please see the line I just added at the end of my post above.  I am using the structure from the tutorial.  How come the tutorial writer was able to do it this way?

Comment: If you build the app with `mvn install`, you're fine. If you build it with Eclipse, you will have additional files on your classpath which you may not want, so be careful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what if I build it with the maven2eclipse plugin?

Comment: I don't know. Just note that a web application's local classpath is take from `WEB-INF/classes`. Right now, everything in `/src/main/webapp` will be copied into `WEB-INF/classes` because it is declared as a source folder on eclipse's build path. You don't want that.

Comment: @MattBall I added the eclipse error log to the end of my original posting above.  Any ideas?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just added an edit to my original posting explaining the results of trying to follow your instructions.  Can you explain how to get eclipse to create a new jsp when I right-click on the folder?  And how do I get the correct contents in the new manifest file I have to create after the old one was lost?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just want a working CRUD example using hibernate 4, a newer version of spring, MySQL, and eclipse that I can get up and running in a couple of hours.  This tutorial has those parameters, except for this error.  Would it be faster for you to suggest a better working example online, or to help me fix this error and make this one work?

Comment: Eclipse might just have a problem. Try restarting it. Otherwise, you can always create the `jsp` file manually in your project directory and just refresh the project view in eclipse (F5).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you. Manually creating the jsp then using F5 worked, but restarting eclipse did not.  Do you have a suggestion for what I can put in the new MANIFEST file I had to create after the original was deleted?

Comment: Why do you want to put anything in the MANIFEST file? You should let the IDE or other build tool (like maven) manage that file.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The MANIFEST had two lines of code in it before it got deleted.  The new one I created is empty.  Are you saying eclipse will handle this so I don't have to worry about it? I want to avoid some tricky bug showing up later because the two lines of code were deleted.

Comment: I really don't think you need to worry about that. As for Eclipse, consider installing or re-installing a newer version.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just added another image to the end of my original posting above.  Should I also move the application.properties file to another location?

Comment: Typically property files are accessed from the classpath, so, no, don't move it. Maven takes all `.java` files in `/src/main/java`, compiles them, and adds them to `WEB-INF/classes`. It does the same with every non-`.java` files in `/src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have eclipse problems..Or sometime it can also be that updating your project (maven update) solve your problem.I just did that and got everything normal.Restart and refresh eclipse and try again .

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to answer this ancient question.  I cannot confirm your answer, because I am on to other things now.  But if someone else confirms your answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted.